# How to remove the association between two Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I want to remove that other account. Both of them are Gmail accounts.
How could I do?[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this association?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sign out from your Gmail account and then login only that one which you want to work with.

The account association is showing through the browser.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much! It works!